# What happens to grudges when their targets aren't available anymore

Tags: warhammer-total-war, warhammer-ii-total-war

When playing as a Dwarf faction, what happens to grudges that can't be completed anymore? For example if there's a grudge against a faction and that faction is destroyed or a grudge against a lord and the lord is killed by another faction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They dissapear and you don't get bonuses. Dissaperead grudges doesn't count to grudge level.

Comment: Thank you. And they stop counting toward your grudge level too, then, right?

Comment: They don't, I added it to answer.